# How to extract the standard registry value type from a legitimate unknown value type?

Tags: c, windows, winapi

## Background

I notice there are many legitimate unknown value types in the HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE of Windows 10. These are just a few of them:

- 0x100000
   `[HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\SYSTEM\DriverDatabase\DriverPackages\hidbthle.inf_amd64_55f7f576bf549669\Configurations\HidBthLE.NT\Device] "WUDF"`
- 0x200000
   
  `[HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\SYSTEM\ControlSet001\Control\Class{4d36e96c-e325-11ce-bfc1-08002be10318}\Configuration\Reset\Driver] "DevLoader"`
- 0x40007
   `[HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\SYSTEM\DriverDatabase\DriverPackages\cdrom.inf_amd64_21e18060f597c313\Configurations\cdrom_install\Services\cdrom] "AutoRunAlwaysDisable"`
- 0xffff0009
    `[HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\SYSTEM\Setup\Upgrade\NetworkDriverBackup\Control\NetworkSetup2\Interfaces{0176DBBA-3617-44FF-BA79-90375AAC4B6A}\Properties{a111f1f4-5923-47c0-9a68-d0bafb577901}\0004] "(Default)"`
- 0xffff000d
    `[HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\SYSTEM\Setup\Upgrade\NetworkDriverBackup\Control\NetworkSetup2\Filters{171C5016-3D19-4CB2-9556-63E586EE5010}\Properties{a111f1f7-5923-47c0-9a68-d0bafb577901}\0002] "(Default)"`
- 0xffff100d
    `[HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\SYSTEM\Setup\Upgrade\NetworkDriverBackup\Control\NetworkSetup2\Filters{E475CF9A-60CD-4439-A75F-0079CE0E18A1}\Properties{a111f1f0-5923-47c0-9a68-d0bafb577901}\0052] "(Default)"`
- 0xffff2012
    `[HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\SYSTEM\Setup\Upgrade\NetworkDriverBackup\Control\NetworkSetup2\Clients{54494F4E-5441-4B53-CCB9-061A6EC4BF6E}\Properties{a111f1f1-5923-47c0-9a68-d0bafb577901}\0002] "(Default)"`

Interestingly, [NirSoft RegScanner](https://www.nirsoft.net/utils/regscanner.html) interprets the value type **0xffff0009** as `REG_FULL_RESOURCE_DESCRIPTOR` (0x09).

Since the predefined constants defined in "winnt.h" (see below) are no more than one byte, my temporary conclusion is that we should **AND** the value type reported by [RegQueryValueEx()](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms724911(v=vs.85).aspx) with **0x000000ff**. However, I'm not sure about this.

```
#define REG_NONE                    ( 0ul ) // No value type
#define REG_SZ                      ( 1ul ) // Unicode nul terminated string
#define REG_EXPAND_SZ               ( 2ul ) // Unicode nul terminated string
                                            // (with environment variable references)
#define REG_BINARY                  ( 3ul ) // Free form binary
#define REG_DWORD                   ( 4ul ) // 32-bit number
#define REG_DWORD_LITTLE_ENDIAN     ( 4ul ) // 32-bit number (same as REG_DWORD)
#define REG_DWORD_BIG_ENDIAN        ( 5ul ) // 32-bit number
#define REG_LINK                    ( 6ul ) // Symbolic Link (unicode)
#define REG_MULTI_SZ                ( 7ul ) // Multiple Unicode strings
#define REG_RESOURCE_LIST           ( 8ul ) // Resource list in the resource map
#define REG_FULL_RESOURCE_DESCRIPTOR ( 9ul ) // Resource list in the hardware description
#define REG_RESOURCE_REQUIREMENTS_LIST ( 10ul )
#define REG_QWORD                   ( 11ul ) // 64-bit number
#define REG_QWORD_LITTLE_ENDIAN     ( 11ul ) // 64-bit number (same as REG_QWORD)
```

## Updates

I just found some discussions about this on the internet:

- https://github.com/williballenthin/python-registry/issues/31
- https://github.com/williballenthin/python-registry/issues/62

However, for some value types, e.g. **0xffff100d**, **AND** it with **0x000000ff**, I get **0x0d**. The problem is there is no standard value types that is defined as **0x0d** in Windows header files.

I still suspect there is a way to conclude the standard value type from a **legitimate** unknown value type.

Please note that I'm not trying to understand how the data should be interpreted. I'm talking about how to extract the standard registry value type from a legitimate unknown registry value type.

This impacts to how we should treat a value type returned by [RegQueryValueEx()](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms724911(v=vs.85).aspx) in our code. Perhaps, the lesson is don't conclude in a hurry that an unknown value type is really unknown; we need to further test the value type with a bitmask.

## Question

How to extract the standard registry value type from a legitimate unknown value type?

Comment: These are "nothing to see here, move on" values.  Only kernel code can interpret them correctly.  If you *have* to display them then just provide a hex dump of the bytes.

Comment: *"How to deal with unknown registry value types?"* - The same way you would deal with any other unknown data type: By not interpreting the data in any way.

Comment: @IInspectable, I think they are not really unknown types? RegScanner interprets `0xffff0009` as `0x09` (REG_FULL_RESOURCE_DESCRIPTOR). Please don't judge a question only by reading its title because the title might be not quite right. I will rephrase the title.

Comment: *"I think they are not really unknown types?"* - Is that a statement or a question? I mean, if you're not even sure about whether you are unsure, then maybe, just maybe you should take the advice from someone, who *knows* what's safe, and what isn't safe. If you have no reason to believe that those unknown types are known, then they are unknown. Treat them as such.

Comment: @IInspectable, it was a statement that needs to be clarified by a knowledgeable person. That statement was issued based on my observation and some discussions on the internet, and also based on the fact that RegScanner interprets 0xffff0009 as 0x09 (REG_FULL_RESOURCE_DESCRIPTOR).  I have a reason to temporary believe that those unknown types are actually known types as I mentioned before.

Comment: This question makes little sense to me. I really can't fathom what you want us to say.

Comment: @David, In the links I gave above, they talked about DEVPROP_MASK_TYPE and DEVPROP_MASK_TYPEMOD. Frankly, I'm not sure about their way because it does not work on some value types (e.g. 0xffff100d) as I described above. I'm eager to know the views of some experts here concerning the matter. Or perhaps, it was documented somewhere in the MSDN.

Comment: The 'experts' already told you: Those types are deliberately not documented. To *you* they are unknown. Treat them like any other unknown type.

Comment: @IInspectable, it is better to say "To all of us they are unknown".

Comment: It isn't. Some of us do have access to internal documentation, and to those the data types aren't unknown.

Comment: For me, it is they that have access to internal documentation, not us.

Comment: really registry subsystem not interpret *Type* value. we can use any dword value for type with any actual data. say under `HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\SYSTEM\Setup\Upgrade\NetworkDriverBackup\Control\NetworkSetup2\Clients\{54494F4E-5441-4B53-CCB9-061A6EC4BF6E}\Properties\{a111f1f0-5923-47c0-9a68-d0bafb577901}` i view several values with `FFFF0019` and `FFFF0012` types. but actual value data - is plain utf-16 string. so actual type is `REG_SZ` here. obviously in this types encoded some additional information for those who understand  this keys sense. this not undocumented type. simply dword data

Comment: NirSoft RegScanner is naively assuming Microsoft follow the documented API, whereas these days they just make it up as they go along.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

registry subsystem not interpret (and not check) the `Type` value of key. it simply store or load it as `DWORD` data. as result we in principle can use any value for type with any data. say for example we can do

```
HKEY hKey;
if (!RegOpenKeyExW(hRootKey, lpSubKey, 0, KEY_SET_VALUE, &hKey))
{
    RegSetValueExW(hKey, 0, 0, 0x87654321, (PBYTE)L"demo", sizeof(L"demo"));
    DWORD ticks = GetTickCount();
    RegSetValueExW(hKey, L"TickCount", 0, 0x12345678, (PBYTE)&ticks, sizeof(ticks));
    RegCloseKey(hKey);
}
```

in other words we can use types `0x87654321` and `0x12345678` instead `REG_SZ` and `REG_DWORD` for example. any value for type is a legitimate. the `Type` is only hint for actual data type. but we for example also can store string with `REG_DWORD` type or `DWORD` with `REG_SZ` type. we can save 0 or not 0-terminating string

> How to extract the standard registry value type from a legitimate
>   unknown value type?

legitimate here excess word. in general case - no way. if you dont know what here saved and what sense of this. we say can display value as `REG_BINARY` - reinterpreted bytes.

for another example, in win10 i view under

```
HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE
  SYSTEM
    Setup
      Upgrade
        NetworkDriverBackup
          Control
            NetworkSetup2
              Clients
                {54494F4E-5441-4B53-CCB9-061A6EC4BF6E}
                  Properties
                    {a111f1f0-5923-47c0-9a68-d0bafb577901}
```

several subkeys with values which type is `0xFFFF0012` and `0xFFFF0019` despite actual value data is `REG_SZ` (easy visible that this is 0-terminating unicode strings)
the `0xFFFF0012` and `0xFFFF0019` - this is some additional information for those who understand this keys sense. they know (hardcode) that actual data here is 0-termanated wide char string. and use `Type` as some additional information (flags ?). anyway - if key/value unknown for you - how you can use it values, if you not understand sense of it. even if know format. for display in UI - only option raw hex view

Comment: Your answer really makes sense to me. Actually, the way RegScanner interpret 0xffff0009 as 0x09 was the one that firstly give me a hint to think like I said before. Thank you very much.

Comment: @Aeoliyan `0xffff0009` this not `0x09`. how interpret `ffff0009` know only who store value with this "type". anyway this is ome additional information about data type. may be flags, may be  something else

Comment: yes, after look at this value type deeper, it turns out that 0xffff0009 does not contains a data for 0x09 (REG_FULL_RESOURCE_DESCRIPTOR).